# QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set off in some stored procedures when migrating 800+ stored procedures using Flyway

Tags: sql-server, flyway, jtds

I'm using [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) for database versioning for my SQL Server 2014 database. I have 800+ stored procedures.

In the initial migration, for around 394 stored procedures, `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is set to `OFF`. But when I migrate it separately having it as the only stored procedure, then the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is set to `ON`.

Always the default value of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`.

I tried setting the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` value (`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER=ON`) in `JTDS` connection string but no use.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

`Quoted_Identifier` and `Ansi_Nulls` and a couple of other pesky attributes are "sticky". The current state of Quoted_Identifier (in the session) controls what "sticks to" a newly introduced procedure or function as they're created. Some tools are better, some worse about scripting out the setting to be inserted *just prior* to the `create procedure` or `create function` statements. You may or may not see the generated statement when you look at the source in the db...depends on the tooling your using.

These attributes are captured into `sys.sql_modules`, which has the source text and the state of `uses_ansi_nulls` and `uses_quoted_identifier` and the other sticky attributes. You can use these flags to know how to script out any statement ahead of the procedure and/or function.

Comment: I'm wondering why the attribute `Quoted_Identifier` is set to `OFF` only for some stored procedures. For an example if i execute 46 stored procedures 6 out of those procedures `Quoted_Identifier` attribute is set to `OFF`. Is there any safe way we can set the `Quoted_Identifier` value to `ON` for a stored procedure during creation if the value is not specifically set to `OFF` ?

Comment: If you don't call `set quoted_identifier on` just ahead of each `create procedure` statement, then the procedure will inherit from current connection settings. These settings are often "infected" by different people (re)creating the procedures without concern for these sticky attributes. If somebody runs `alter procedure` it will pick up the ambient settings at that time, too.